# How to find source of a symbolic link?

Tags: command-line, symbolic-link

Say fileA is a sym link to fileB. I have only fileB at hand and want to find all files that are sym links to fileB. Is there a command to show this in *nix?

Answer (score 6):

Have you googled?

```
find / -lname linktarget
```